# Having trouble with my jQuery plugin parameters not firing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, jquery-plugins

I am working with many aging applications and what i need to do is tap into the applications and pull the html tables and display them on a new page and then update the code styles there. I have created a plugin for the ajax call and I want to feed it parameters for the url and the target ID then display them on the page in different sections. The problem is that it takes whatever the last parameters are in the scope and uses them across all the function calls within the doc.ready.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.getAppData = function(options) {
            data = $.extend({
                target: $(this),
                id: "body",
                url: "/error/404error.html",
                callback: function(){}
            }, options );
            $.ajax({
                url: data.url,
                cache: false
            })
            .done(function( html ) {
                //alert(data.id);
                $display = $(html).find('div'+data.id);
                data.target.append($display);
                options.callback.call(this);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert('Error loading '+data.id+' data.');
            });
        }
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Here is the calls in the doc.ready statement:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#bulletinBoard').getAppData({
    target: $('#bulletinBoard'),
    id: '#tabs-1',
    url: '/webapps/BulletinBoard/default.cfm',
    callback: function() {
        //manipulate the new loaded html here
    }
});
$('#VTCSchedule').getAppData({
    target: $('#VTCSchedule'),
    id: "#vtcInfo",
    url: "/webapps/VTCInfo/default.cfm",
    callback: function() {
        //manipulate the new loaded html here
    }
});
$('#askMGMT').getAppData({
    target: $('#askMGMT'),
    id: "#askMGMT",
    url: "/webapps/askthera/AskTheRIIManagement.asp",
    callback: function() {
        //manipulate the new loaded html here
    }
});
});
```

This is probably a bone head move but I am not seeing the problem and I do not have much time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note your ajax url: `data.url`. This is always going to be "/error/404error.html" how you currently have it. You should have data.url pull from `options`:

```
 $.fn.getAppData = function(options) {
        $this = $(this);
        data = $.extend({
            id: options.id, // <- this is now dynamic
            url: options.url, // <- this is now dynamic
            callback: function(){}
        }, options );
```

Same thing with `data.id`.

**Edit**

I was wrong! The issue is with `data =`. Because you are missing `var`, you are assigning `data` to the global scope, thus overwriting it with each new call to this method. I would instead use the following:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.getAppData = function(options) {
            $this = $(this);
            var data = $.extend({ // <- Only available in current scope because of "var"!
                id: "body",
                url: "/error/404error.html",
                callback: function(){}
            }, options );
            $.ajax({
                url: data.url,
                cache: false
            })
            .done(function( html ) {
                //alert(data.id);
                $display = $(html).find('div'+data.id);
                $this.append($display);
                options.callback.call(this);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert('Error loading '+data.id+' data.');
            });
        //Also note, that there was an extra bracket "}" here
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Those are default parameters and it currently isn't always "/error/404error.html"

Comment: Ah, my bad. I misread the `$.extend` method. I see the issue. I will update my answer...

Comment: HA I knew it was a bonehead move but I found another problem (which I fixed) as it loses the target id as well and adds all the data to the last div but I will edit the code to fix that and check your answer

Comment: That issue should be fixed once the scope is fixed (in my answer). No worries, we are all allowed to make a bonehead move on Friday! :D